# Write a .bat file to select a certain portion of an output of a batch command into a batch file variable

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

If I run the following command on my windows 7 system (where cable is the name of my network adapter)

```
netsh interface ip show ipaddresses cable
```

I get the following result:

```
Address 10.17.179.17 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : Cable
Scope Id           : 0.0
Valid Lifetime     : 22h46m12s
Preferred Lifetime : 22h46m12s
DAD State          : Deprecated
Address Type       : Dhcp
Skip as Source     : false
```

For this section of my batch file I only care about getting the IP address (in this example 10.17.179.17) into a variable for later use.
The IP address changes everyday or so, so that is why I require a variable.

so effectively I want the result of:

```
@SET IPaddyVariableName=10.17.179.17
@SET IPaddyVariableName= <some batch file code I need help with as 10.17.179.17 is hardcoded>
```

Please help me get `10.17.179.17` (which obviously changes) into a variable? Once it's in a variable I'm sorted.
Thanks all!

Comment: Your code doesn't actually work for me `netsh interface ip show ipaddresses cable`

Comment: I believe this will answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898763/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-into-a-batch-file-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My connection is named **Local Area Connection**...

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('netsh interface ip show ipaddresses "Local Area Connection" ^| findstr /r "Address[\s]*[^\s]*[\s]*Parameters"') do @set IPaddyVariableName=%%a

echo.
echo %IPaddyVariableName%
echo.
```